# SQLDataSource: Running the select command multiple times with changing parameter (or array parameters?)

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I'm currently running a VB.net/ASPX web app that grabs specific records from a database depending upon a users security group level. What I want to do is if the user is from multiple security groups - to grab reports for each security group they exist in.

In the where clause, this line exists:
`and b.security_level_id = @security_level_id`

This only allows for one `security_level_id` to be passed into the select query.

Is it possible to run the query multiple times, changing the parameter:

`<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="security_level_id" />`

or can I make an array out of this parameter and loop through it in a single query?

Thanks!

SOLVED:

Ok. I Solved this issue by creating the select command in my actual VB code.. It removed the need for parameters so I could pass variables directly into the query string.

I used:
 Protected Sub SqlDS_ReportCategories_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SqlDS_ReportCategories.Init

to get a handle on my data source, followed by:
Dim s As SqlDataSource = CType(sender, SqlDataSource)
To create an object reference of it.

then 
s.SelectCommand ="some query" + Variable + "rest of query"

Hope this helps people in the future!

- Mat

Comment: What do you use to make your query?

Comment: I used the 'SelectCommand' parameter for the <asp:SqlDataSource object

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

Ok. I Solved this issue by creating the select command in my actual VB code.. It removed the need for parameters so I could pass variables directly into the query string.

I used: Protected Sub SqlDS_ReportCategories_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SqlDS_ReportCategories.Init

to get a handle on my data source, followed by: Dim s As SqlDataSource = CType(sender, SqlDataSource) To create an object reference of it.

then s.SelectCommand ="some query" + Variable + "rest of query"

Hope this helps people in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL `IN` to search for multiple items simultaneously.

The first thing to do is gather the security levels into a comma-delimited list:

```
Dim sbSQL As New System.Text.StringBuilder(500)

For Each wSecurityLevel As Integer In theUser.SecurityLevels
    If sbSQL.Length <> 0 Then
        sbSQL.Append(",")     
    End If
    sbSQL.Append(wSecurityLevel)
Next
```

then setup your SQL statement to use IN:

```
"and b.security_level_id IN (" & sbSQL.ToString() & ")"
```

Comment: I've figured most of it out, but now the database is complaining about
"Syntax error converting the nvarchar value '3,5,5,99' to a column of data type int." So i'm unsure as to what to do next.

Comment: Make sure you don't wrap the list of values in quotes: if you do, SQL will treat it like a long string instead of individual values.

Comment: Obligatory link to Erland Sommarskog's page: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html